# How to call vuex dispatch without remembering names of all actions and send them from dispatch as string?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

Doing it like:

```
this.$store.dispatch({
      type: "getUsers",
      data
    }).then(() => {})
```

is just annoying. You have to know methods names.

I have something like:

```
class UserModule extends ListModule<UserState, any, api.UserListItemModel> {

  actions = {

    // ActionContext requires two arguments State and root state
    async getAll(context: ActionContext<UserState, any>, data: Data) {}
  }
}
```

Hot to call that `actions.getUsers` without that string thingy? Having typescript should have autocomplete in editor so i dont have to remember action names and to dispatch in that matter.

I mean creating some map with names maybe the answer but not sure that i want to create map with 1000 names.

Comment: You can use enum.

Comment: @jacky can you be more specific?

Comment: Just use the enumeration value as the name of the action,for easily typing and remembering

Comment: for 1000 dispatch actions, think not ...

Answer (score 0):

I got resolved with this: https://github.com/istrib/vuex-typescript.
It says:

> No string literals or constants for action/mutation/getter names No
>
> action/mutation/getter misuse by providing wrong payload type
>
> Intellisense giving unambiguous hints on what type of payload or getter arguments is expected